# How to combine same user_id data with PostgreSQL query

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a functional query which returns all of the data from three tables where the `user_id` is the same.  However my search is returning the `user_id` three times (once from each table). I have tried using `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` to eliminate this duplication but haven't had any luck. I know I can specify each column to be returned however this creates a much longer query as my questionnaire table is likely to have many columns.

Query

```
SELECT * FROM users, budget, questionnaire WHERE users.user_id = 'google-708342' AND budget.user_id = 'google-708342' AND questionnaire.user_id = 'google-708342' GROUP BY users.user_id, budget.user_id, questionnaire.user_id;
```

The result comes like this

```
user_id         first_name  last_name  user_id        budget  user_id        favorite_color
google-708342     Jon         Jonson   google-708342    0     google-708342   red
```

I obviously don't want the `user_id` three times.  It seems like the `GROUP BY` or `JOIN` could take care of this but I haven't had any success.

Comment: Stop using "Select *". Name the columns you actually want.

Comment: @Belayer, this is specifically what I am trying to avoid.  I don't want an excessively long query that boils down to select all non-repeating columns

Comment: Then you must live with duplicate columns with user_id in the result. You can name the necessary columns, select **all** of of them, or perhaps select you can select all from specific tables as "select users.*, budget.column_name, ...".